# variable value not assigned in cronjob

Tags: sql, linux, bash, cron

I have a code which when executed manually ( via this command i.e. ./script.sh ) assigns the query result to a variable but when it is executed automatically via crontab then the query result is not assigned to the variable.

Please find below the code:

```
diff=0;

diff=`sqlplus -s user/pswd@leadb2 << END
      set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
      SELECT (to_Date($timeRightNow,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') - to_date($timeoffile,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ) * 24 * 60
      difference_in_minutes
      from dual;
END`



echo "Difference is $diff ">>/backup2/softdev/settlement/p.txt
```

Comment: I think from crontab you need to give the full path of sqlplus

Comment: Use `exit;` before `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it as cron doesnot know the path of SQLPlus so it does not execute the query as soon as the path is given to cron the job responds perfectly

Here is the solution:

ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
export ORACLE_HOME

dateToday=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

diff=0;

timeRightNow='20170519180000'
timeoffile='20170519175500'

diff=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s user/paswd@leadb2 << END
      set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
      SELECT (to_Date($timeRightNow,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') - to_date($timeoffile,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') ) * 24 * 60
      difference_in_minutes
      from dual;
END`

echo "Difference is $diff ">>/backup2/softdev/settlement/p.txt

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens because your cron is not aware of your variables initialized in .profile. Even the path for sqlplus is not available, when you run this script via cron. So, to fix the issue, set the cron job in below format, and it will work fine.

```
    00 * * * * . ~/.profile && /home/absolut_path_to_script.sh > /home/log_file_path.txt
```

Comment: used to set environmental items for a users shell. Items such as umask, and variables such as PS1 or PATH.